# View Source and View Generated Source in firefox addons Web Developer

Tags: php, session, firefox

I use Firefox Web developer everyday.

Now I found some of my website need to use View Generated Source rather than View Source.

Because View Source gives a blank outputs.

It seems it is relating to the following code.

I am hoping someone can tell me why it needs View Generated source.

And is there anyway I can modify the code so that I don't need to worry about it.

Or I don't need to worry about it?

I use PHP/MySQL.

```
 if (!isset($_SESSION['userid']) || $_SESSION['userid'] < 1){
    redirect('welcome/verify','refresh');
}
```

Comment: This question seems to be very closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066478/why-i-am-not-able-to-see-source-code-with-ff-when-i-have-this-if-statement

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).  It will allow you to see the rendered HTML as well as browse the DOM and see what is sent to and from the browser in great detail.